# Tracking an order ID with node.js & MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

So I have a strange problem that I have been scratching my head about for a few days now and I cant seem to find any online solutions.

I am developing an ordering service on a mobile application that uses unique orderID's each time an order is placed.

Each day, the order ID base value is reset back to 100, and then when orders are placed that day, it increments like: 101, 102, 103, 104 etc.

My OrderID is caculated based from the amount of 'active orders' in a collection named `orders`, +1. So if there are 5 active orders, the new order ID returned to the customer is 106. This works fine except for one problem:

- I have 4 instances of my node.js API working at the same time, to balance the load.
- All of these nodes are connected to the same mongo database.

So if two orders are placed in parallel, instance 1 & 2 take an order each, both ask the database how many 'active orders' there are, and they obviously both get the same value because it is happening pretty much at the same time. Therefore they both return the same order ID and we then have two customers with the same order ID.

If I reduce my setup back to one instance then this works perfect as it eliminates the possiblty of orders being run in parallel. However, for HA & Load Balancing I need to be able to scale up horizontally with multiple instances.

Is there a standard practice that avoid this type of scenario? Are there better ways to track orderID's like this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mutex locks which are used to prevent access to resources at the same time. So basically, the process will have access when the lock is free (unlocked). Otherwise, it'll wait until it's free to use. You can find one module that does that for you here: [locks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/locks)

**Edit:**

The other solution could prevent the parallel processing of the 4 instances you have. So what you can do is that you can implement a queue based approach for that too. Here's a module that will help you with that : [MongoDB-Queue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-queue)
And you can refer to this article as well : [Medium-MongoDB-Queue](https://medium.com/@dltlabs/mongodb-queue-and-processing-in-distributed-systems-a805b32f6e76)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer - this looks good, but during operation I am expecting 100s of orders, so would this 'locking' defeat the purpose of my horizontal scaling and running orders in parallel?

Comment: Well, running one transaction at a time should not take that long to process, so the parallel effect technically should still be there. You can still try it, otherwise, you can implement your own "Queue" w a FIFO approach. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: The queue based approach is exactly what I was looking for and also solves another future issue I know I would come into contact with - so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve load balancing but still prevent order from same customer from going to multiple instances by having a custom layer before the actual processing programs that will route a particular customer's request to a specific node only. This can be done by doing hash and modulo operations on, say, the customer id and then determining the node to which it should be routed. Since this "router" layer is basically just a custom proxy and doesn't do additional processing - there should not be any impact on performance.